# scala error: found and required are same

Tags: scala

Following code is from my REPL:

```
scala> words.zipWithIndex.filter((x:java.lang.String,index:Int)=>index%2==0)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
found : (java.lang.String, Int) => Boolean
required: (java.lang.String, Int) => Boolean
words.zipWithIndex.filter((x:java.lang.String,index:Int)=>index%2==0)
```

Here found and required are the same. Could anyone help me understand the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are not really the same -- that's just a badly formatted error message. Scala 2.10 will have a better error message.

Basically, one is a tuple while the other is a two-parameters argument list. Specifically:

```
words.zipWithIndex // Creates a tuple

(x: String, index: Int) => index % 2 == 0 // is a function with two parameters
```

You can fix it in two ways:

```
filter((t: (String, Index)) => t._2 % 2 == 0) // use a tuple as parameter
filter { case (x: String, index: Int) => index % 2 == 0 } // use pattern matching
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I should update to newest version of scala perhaps. Also, I found a better way of filtering which allows me disregard the type of list element: e.g. list.filter(x=> x._something....)

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 Scala 2.10 is not available yet. Version 2.9.1 is the latest, but I can assure you that 2.10 will have a better error message.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I'm assuming you meant `filter(t: (String, Int))`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Mind you that I wrote this 3 years ago, but I don't think I did. It looks correct to me up there.